# django invalid literal for int() with base 10 get_prep_value

Tags: python, django, int, literals, radix

I am running out of ideas with fixing the issue with invalid literal for int().

It worked originally but than I have changed something and now I am getting this issue. I have set the project from the beginning and set db from scratch again but it did not help as well.

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Zone(models.Model):
    zone_name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    zone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('zone_name',)      

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.zone_name  


class Stage(models.Model):
    stage_number = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    stage_name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    zones = models.ManyToManyField(Zone, through='ZoneStage')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('stage_number',)      

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.stage_number  


class ZoneStage(models.Model):
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone)
    stage = models.ForeignKey(Stage)
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('zone',)          

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.zone, self.stage)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic

from models import Zone, Stage, ZoneStage
#from models import SubStage, ZoneSubStage

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'autostages/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'stages'
    queryset = Stage.objects.order_by('stage_number')[:12]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['zones'] = Zone.objects.all()
        context['zone_stages'] = ZoneStage.objects.all()
#        context['substages'] = SubStage.objects.all()

        # And so on for more models
        return context    


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'autostages/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'stages'
    queryset = Stage.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['zones'] = Zone.objects.all()
#        context['zone_substages'] = ZoneSubStage.objects.all()
#        context['substages'] = SubStage.objects.all()

        # And so on for more models
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='stage_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\w+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    ]
```

**index.html**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:40px" >
        <td style="width:100px">
        {% for zone in zones|dictsort:"zone_name" %}
            <td style="width:40px" align="center">{{ zone.zone_name }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% for stage in stages %}
        <tr>
            <td style="width:40px"><a href="{% url 'autostages:detail' stage %}">{{ stage.stage_number }}
            </a></td>
            <td style="width:40px">{{ stage.stage_name }}</td>

                {% for zone in zones|dictsort:"zone_name" %}
                    <td style="width:40px" align="center">
                    {% for zs in stage.zonestage_set.all %}
                    {% if zs.zone == zone %} {{ stage.value}}{% endif %}
                    <!--{% if zs.zone == zone %} {{ zs.value}}{% endif %}-->
                    {% endfor %}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

**detail.html**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:40px"></td>
        <td style="width:100px"></td>    

        {% for zone in zones|dictsort:"zone_name" %}
        {{ zone }}
           <td style="width:40px" align="center">{{ zone.zone_name }}</td>
        {% endfor %}

        </tr>
                <td style="width:40px">{{ stages }}</td>
        <td style="width:100px">{{ stages.stage_name }}</td> 
        {% for substage in stages.substage_set.all %}
        <tr>
            <td style="width:40px"></td>
            <td style="width:40px">{{ substage.sub_name }}</td>
                {% for zone in zones|dictsort:"zone_name" %}
                    <td style="width:40px" align="center">
                    {% for zss in substage.zonesubstage_set.all %}
                    {% if zss.zone == zone %} {{ zss.value}}{% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}

    </tr>

{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Django traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/autostages/S1/

Django Version: 1.8.4
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'autostages')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get
  115.         self.object = self.get_object()
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get_object
  38.             queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  679.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  697.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1309.         clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1337.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1208.             condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_lookup
  1101.                 return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in __init__
  101.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  139.         return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs)
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  727.             return self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/home/dkr103/Coding/projects/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  985.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /autostages/S1/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'S1'
```

Comment: You're somehow doing `int("S1")`, which obviously won't work.

Comment: Is `S1` stage number?

Comment: I have just double check it. Originally I had primary_key=True in class Stage stage_number field. I removed it and this is what caused me a problem. Now I have added it again and problem disappears. I do not want to use primary_key=True and I would like to remove it from that field but I do not know how to fix the issue i get.

Comment: No, i meant `stage_number` field value?

Comment: stage_number is CharField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have incorrectly passed the `stage` object instead of `stage.pk` as argument in `url` template tag in the `index.html` page.

Try changing

```
{% url 'autostages:detail' stage %}
```

to

```
{% url 'autostages:detail' stage.pk %}
```

Actually, when you were passing `stage` object as the argument, then its representation which you have defined in your model i.e. `stage_number` was being used as the value of the argument. `S1` not being an integer led to the error.

Comment: Yes, that's it. It helps. It works if I use stage.pk or stage.id now. Cheers for help ! So, I guess the problem was caused by passing string and not int value.

Comment: Yes, the representation of the object i.e. `stage_number`was being used as the value of `pk` leading to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly You have this issue when you trying to add or read data with int field models in your case verify that value field receive only positive small int